# DataAnnotations and tag helper - why is the expected string not shown on validation error?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used the tag helper for validation summary

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-warning"></div>
```

but instead of the expected `The {0} field is required` the string `RequiredAttribute_ValidationError` shows:

```
<div class="text-warning validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul>
    <li>RequiredAttribute_ValidationError</li>
</ul></div>
```

What do I need to do to get the expected `The {0} field is required` value?

---

**dnvm output**

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta4          mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-beta5-11576    mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-beta5-11744    mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-beta7          coreclr x64          darwin          
       1.0.0-beta7          mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-beta8          coreclr x64          darwin          
  *    1.0.0-beta8          mono                 linux/osx       default
       1.0.0-rc2-16128      coreclr x64          darwin          
       1.0.0-rc2-16128      mono                 linux/osx
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug with mono.

Quick workaround, specify the `ErrorMessage` format:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the DisplayAttribute to your required view model property? The validation summary will use the display name attribute to populate the validation error.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, already got DisplayAttribute on my model property. As far as per all the examples I have seen so am suspecting it might be to do with mono but not sure where to look.